# vue-i18n dynamic locale with promise doesn't update

Tags: javascript, promise, vue-resource

I am testing `vue-i18n` in order to implement it for my future projects. I have a separate system to handle the translations, so I got remote json files. `vue-i18n` have a system to fetch the locale using a promise, explainations  [here](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/dynamic.html).

I cannot use the fetch method because my files are outside so I got cross-origin troubles. Instead I do it with `vue-resource`, but I don't know why, when I set a new set of locale, it doesn't update automatically. bescause the default lang is `en`, when I load my `en` locale file, it does nothing. I have to change two times the `config.lang` to force update.

Several things:

- A jsfiddle to test > http://jsfiddle.net/t4kdoqj7/3/ uncomment line 19 to reproduce the fix
- Maybe it's just due to a bad using of `vue-resource`
- I couldn't create a `vue-i18n` tag...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found a hack :

Set `Vue.config.lang = ''` before loading anything

Here the fiddle (l9) > http://jsfiddle.net/t4kdoqj7/4/